# Some issues with Python loading packages

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've been running into this same issue no matter what I do. I'm running Python on Spyder (custom python 3.7.9) and I keep getting errors when importing packages.

```
from pandas import dataframe
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

The above are the modules in question which won't import. The errors I'm getting are:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dataframe' from 'pandas' (C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\__init__.py)

&


  File "<ipython-input-8-4c3b6a7a4279>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Using `pip install <some package>`  doesn't seem to work either, even after resarting my Kernal. I tried to uninstall and reinstall and that doesn't work. Other modules in the ``pandas`package import for me. Nothing from`sklearn`seems to import. I even sepcified the exact location of the package in`PYTHONPATH Manager`and it still won't import`sklearn`and`pandas`doesn't seem to have the`dataframe``` module file included. I'm not sure how to ensure I get everything I need installed and imported.

EDIT: fixed the simple typo of `dataframe` instead of `DataFrame`. The main issue is now `sklearn` which has given me consistent issues across multiple scripts. `setup.py` method doesn't work, just keeps giving me the error that `sklearn` isn't found when trying to run the setup.

Comment: It is not `dataframe` it is `DataFrame `

Comment: Wow, what an oversight. That section works perfectly. Just seems ```sklearn``` or ```scikit-learn``` doesn't install properly. Trying the ```setup.py``` but it gives me the same error that the module isn't found.

Comment: How did you install scikit-learn, what version of python are you using and are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I attempt to install from ```pip```, did not seem to work. So I am attempting to install from Git source but loading the setup is still giving me the same error. I am working in Spyder IDE version 5.0.5 and using Python 3.7.9.

Comment: How did you install Python? Where is the specific Python environment in which Spyder is running?

Comment: Make sure you are installing scikit-learn in the same environment you are using in your IDE. You should just be able to `pip install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: @ifly6 The specific environment is ```C:\\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\python.exe```. I'm not sure I understand your question about Python, I just followed the directions of installing through Python.org. I am NOT using the Anaconda version of Spyder though, I can tell you that.

Comment: @It_is_Chris This helps. But, to do this I have to go outside of my IDE to a command line, correct? The problem is the interpreter for Spyder doesn't seem to be a valid environment directory command prompt can use. Unless you mean something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install `miniconda` if you are not using Spyder in Anaconda. You can then find out how to set this environment here: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer

You can install packages using `conda install <some package>` after setting the environment to the `miniconda` environment.

Comment: Additional: using ```help``` or checking the Spyder FAQ will bring you to this same solution. If you are attempting to install a package that does not come with Spyder, the suggested method is to use ```miniconda```.